# Are HTML Applications (.hta) Cross-Browser

Tags: cross-browser, hta

**Can HTML Applications (.hta) run in Firefox, Chrome and Safari (Windows OS Version)?**

I understand that HTML Applications(.hta) require Windows (because of the requirement for the engine mshta.exe) and are not Cross-Platform. But are HTML Applications Cross-Browser?

If they are not natively Cross-Browser are there maybe 3rd party libraries that allow you to run HTML Applications on other browsers other than IE? For example maybe there are browser plugins that enable this?

Comment: See previous question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10623962/754456 - doesn't sound like they'll run except in IE. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/992751/754456 that explains about permissions (.htas normally have system access, a no-go from IE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTAs are not cross-browser, as mshta.exe always instantiates the IE rendering engine.

You may be able to open HTAs in some browsers by renaming their extensions, but they may have reduced functionality due to unsupported HTA tags or the lack of things like VBScript, OS permissions, etc., if the HTA is using it.

Related question: [HTA's; use other browser to host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992695/htas-use-other-browser-to-host)

Comment: Firefox IE tab may help here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/ie-tab/